# Determine which field is being modified during OnChangeFeature event

Tags: arcobjects

In the OnChangeFeature event is there a way to determine which field was just edited causing the event to fire?  I'm doing several tasks in OnChangeFeature that only need to happen when certain fields are edited, so being able to determine which field just changed would be helpful.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try [IRowChanges](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000007vw000000) and loop through each field to see if ValueChanged is true?

Comment: That is the way to go. I was going to answer but Kirk is like Skeet from SO. :P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why everyone is commenting instead of answering but here's an example with both an IRowChanges and an IFeatureChanges (in case you are interested in the geometry). I did have to strip out some lines of code, but this should be close:

IRowChanges:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000007vw000000

```
        IRowChanges rowChanges = obj as IRowChanges;

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.Fields.FieldCount; i++)
        {
                if (rowChanges.ValueChanged[i])
                {
                    object oldValue = rowChanges.get_OriginalValue(i);
                    object newValue = obj.get_Value(i);     


                }
            }
        }
```

IFeatureChanges:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002qp000000

```
        IFeatureChanges featureChanges = obj as IFeatureChanges;

        if (featureChanges != null && featureChanges.ShapeChanged)
        {
            // Do something
            // featureChanges.OriginalShape
        }
```

Comment: You can use IRow for the geometry field as well. All you have to do is to pass up the index of the geometry field.

Comment: IRowChanges is exactly what I was looking for.  I'd give Kirk answer points as well if I could.  Thanks to all.