# How to prevent the user from moving the feature?

Tags: arcmap, editing, events

I want to prevent the user from moving the feature in ArcMap when editing.
I used `OnChangeFeature` event but it does not work.

```
void m_editEvents_OnChangeFeature(IObject obj)
        {
            m_editor.AbortOperation();
        }
```

The `OnChangeFeature` event fired after moving the faeture.

Comment: Instead of aborting, did you consider casting obj to IFeatureChanges, as show [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11975/59) and setting it back to its OriginalShape?